# How can I build multiple products with different dependency versions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm building a Ruby C Extensions and I have to build for both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 2.0. The source code is the same, but I have to link to different Ruby libs and set different build paths.

In Xcode I was able to set up a project where the project contained the common configuration. Then I set up two targets that configured different include paths and libs as well as different output (Debug/Release) paths.

When I build I will get two products built, one for each targeted Ruby version. When I build Release I get:

- build/Release/1.8/Example.bundle
- build/Release/2.0/Example.bundle

Now I am trying to do the same thing for Visual Studio 2010. I've been looking at the Configuration Manager and Property Sheets, but I'm struggling to fond out how I can make the same type of inheritance for the targets as I can in Xcode.

1. Is it possible to have multiple targets in VS, as you can in Xcode, that produce two products from the same project when you build?
2. Do I have to create a Debug and Release configuration for each Ruby core I want to target?

Comment: VisualStudio, though superior to Xcode in many aspects, utterly fails on that side. Their configuration model is entirely static and has no such thing as the multilayer inheritance that Xcode has (Project, Target, Scheme, Configuration). However, you should be able to at least build all of those (statically prepared) configurations in an automised way via commandline.

Comment: Yea, as I'm new to both Xcode and VS I do generally prefer VS. Especially VS2013. So I was surprised to find this to be so awkward in VS. I did find that there is a Batch Build command in the UI - still not as slick as in Xcode, but it might just have to do for now. I might have to look into command line tools as you suggest.

Comment: You can use `devenv.exe` to build projects on the command line, but I don't think that you can build more than one config on each invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are looking for (but I can't be sure, as I have no experience with Xcode.)

If you are using Visual Studio, one way you can do something like this is to set up you project properties for a build configuration (e.g. for Release) and then *copy* that config into a new build type (e.g. call it "Release20") and go in and change the properties that you want for the new build. You can do this in "Configuration Manager". (When you select to add a new configuration, it lets you copy all properties from an existing one.)

However, it seems that you are already familiar with this, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Another thing you should know is that the two build configs don't stay linked together (this is not a proper inheritance and overriding of properties, like using property sheets.) If you change something in one, it doesn't affect the other.

Precisely for these reasons (in addition to some others) I myself have foregone trying to wrangle the VS build system. I now use Premake and CMake for all my projects. But of course it's quite a chore building a build system for someone else's large code base.

Comment: Setting up inherited properties is one thing. I think I can work with that in VS using the Configurations even though it doesn't have the same inheritance as Xcode projects. But another thing I was trying to do was building two different configurations at the same time. Like in Xcode where you can configure two targets to build at the same time generating two binaries from the same source.

Comment: And I'm not really familiar with VS configurations, I've jsut been reading up on it and I cannot seem to find a way to make it work as I'd hoped I'd be able to.

Comment: @thomthom: Build configurations are kinda the same thing. They use the same source files, but build different targets with different settings. However, you must build them separately (or use "Batch Build" command in the IDE.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I hoped I'd missed something.